# How to sort rows of a matrix by decreasing values of the first column in Python and numpy?

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix with `N = 250000` rows and `M = 10` columns.
I want to sort the matrix for decreasing values of the first column,
so I write:

```
matrix=np.loadtxt("matrix.dat")

np.sort(matrix)

matrix=matrix[::-1]
```

But the `np.sort` does not work. In fact, once printing the values after sorting, I find the same input matrix.
Anyone knows how to resolve this problem?
Thank you very much

Comment: "I want to sort the matrix for decreasing values of the first column" : so you only want to sort the first column ?

Comment: sorted_matrix = np.sort(matrix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will sort a matrix for decreasing values of the first column

```
import numpy as np

# Generate a matrix of data
matrix = np.random.rand(5,4)

# Find the ordering of the first column (in increasing order)
ind = np.argsort(matrix[:,0])

# Switch the ordering (so it's decreasing order)
rind = ind[::-1]

# Return the matrix with rows in the specified order
matrix = matrix[rind]
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.sort()` doesn't sort your matrix in-place, you have to assign the sorted matrix to your previous variable, or use `array.sort(axis=0)` method for in-place sorting. Then reverse the result if you want it in decreasing order.

Demo:

```
In [33]: arr = np.random.rand(5, 4)

In [34]: arr
Out[34]: 
array([[ 0.80270779,  0.14277011,  0.01316072,  0.67149683],
       [ 0.16252499,  0.9969757 ,  0.14759736,  0.24212889],
       [ 0.49493771,  0.51692399,  0.17731137,  0.40797518],
       [ 0.20700147,  0.13279386,  0.2464658 ,  0.9730963 ],
       [ 0.26145694,  0.23410809,  0.78049016,  0.45821089]])

In [35]: arr.sort(0) # or arr.sort(axis=0, kind='mergesort')

In [36]: arr
Out[36]: 
array([[ 0.16252499,  0.13279386,  0.01316072,  0.24212889],
       [ 0.20700147,  0.14277011,  0.14759736,  0.40797518],
       [ 0.26145694,  0.23410809,  0.17731137,  0.45821089],
       [ 0.49493771,  0.51692399,  0.2464658 ,  0.67149683],
       [ 0.80270779,  0.9969757 ,  0.78049016,  0.9730963 ]])

In [37]: arr[::-1]
Out[37]: 
array([[ 0.80270779,  0.9969757 ,  0.78049016,  0.9730963 ],
       [ 0.49493771,  0.51692399,  0.2464658 ,  0.67149683],
       [ 0.26145694,  0.23410809,  0.17731137,  0.45821089],
       [ 0.20700147,  0.14277011,  0.14759736,  0.40797518],
       [ 0.16252499,  0.13279386,  0.01316072,  0.24212889]])
```